# Using Windsor In Winforms

Tags: .net, winforms, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am using Windsor in windows application. I create a container and register components without any problems, but once i try to resolve anything, i get the following errorL

```
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentResolutionException: 'Looks like you forgot to register the http module Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule
To fix this add
<add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
to the <httpModules> section on your web.config.
If you plan running on IIS in Integrated Pipeline mode, you also need to add the module to the <modules> section under <system.webServer>.
Alternatively make sure you have Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 assembly in your GAC (it is installed by ASP.NET MVC3 or WebMatrix) and Windsor will be able to register the module automatically without having to add anything to the config file.
```

I have tried adding the `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure`, but that didn't help. I modified my `app.config` to this, but still no luck. I am still getting the same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="castle"
      type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. The issue was using the `LifestylePerWebRequest`. Other life styles should be used such as PerThread or Transient. Everything will work fine then.